# Insert variables from axios response into exported const

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using axios in my vue.js project to do an HTTP POST and gather some variables for a vue-echart. I am trying to figure out the best way to do this and have somewhat hit a roadblock.

This is what is in my dashboard.vue file:

```
<script>

import { echartBar, echartPie } from "@/data/echarts";

import { echart1, echart2, echart3 } from "@/data/dashboard1";

export default {
  metaInfo: {
    title: "Dashboard v1"
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .post('https://testsite.com', 'Request data here')
      .then(response => {
        this.dataNeeded = response.data
        console.log(info)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)
  },
  data() {
    return {
      echartBar,
      echartPie,
      echart1,
      echart2,
      echart3,
    };
  }
};
</script>
<style>
.echarts {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Then, here's the exported const from echarts.js:

```
var dark_heading = "#c2c6dc";
var chartLabels = ['Test1', 'Test2']

import { zoomBarData } from '@/data/echartSeries'

// start::echartBar
export const echartBar = {
        legend: {
            borderRadius: 0,
            orient: 'horizontal',
            x: 'right',
            data: chartLabels
        },
        grid: {
            left: '8px',
            right: '8px',
            bottom: '0',
            containLabel: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            show: true,
            
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)'
        },
        
        xAxis: [{
            type: 'category',
          
            data: dataNeeded.months,
            axisTick: {
                alignWithLabel: true,
               
            },
            splitLine: {
                show: false
            },
            axisLabel: {
                color: dark_heading,
            },
            axisLine: {
                show:true,
                color: dark_heading,
                
                lineStyle: {
                color: dark_heading,
                
                }
            }
        }],
        yAxis: [{
          type: 'value',
          
        
          axisLabel: {
            color: dark_heading, 
            formatter: '${value}'
        },
        axisLine: {
            show:false,
            color: dark_heading,
            
            lineStyle: {
            color: dark_heading,
            
            }
        },
          min: 0,
          max: 100000,
          interval: 25000,
      
          splitLine: {
              show: true,
              interval: 'auto'
          }
      }],
 

  series: [{
          name: chartLabels[0],
          data: dataNeeded.amounts,
          label: { show: false, color: '#0168c1' },
          type: 'bar',
          barGap: 0,
          color: '#bcbbdd',
          smooth: true,
          itemStyle: {
              emphasis: {
                  shadowBlur: 10,
                  shadowOffsetX: 0,
                  shadowOffsetY: -2,
                  shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'
              }
          }
      },
      {
          name: chartLabels[1],
          data: dataNeeded.amounts2,
          label: { show: false, color: '#639' },
          type: 'bar',
          color: '#7569b3',
          smooth: true,
          itemStyle: {
              emphasis: {
                  shadowBlur: 10,
                  shadowOffsetX: 0,
                  shadowOffsetY: -2,
                  shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'
              }
          }
      }

  ]
}
```

Basically, if I'd like to use data coming back from the axios request (JSON) in place of the data listed in echarts.js (being an exported const), what would be my best option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I'm not the biggest HTTP verb stickler, but why are GETting data with a POST request?

Comment: I don't think that answers my question - seems a bit different than what I'm looking for. I have an exported const from a different file that is being imported into the same page that has the axios request. From here, I need to put some of the response variables into the imported const. The endpoint is requiring a POST that returns some info. Apologies if I'm not making much sense.

Comment: The const is basically returning a plain object. Axios will probably also receive such an object. So did you try setting your echartBar variable to the axios response, like `this.echartBar = response`?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman, it'd likely be `this.echartBar = response.data` that the OP would want instead, though you might have to go deeper, depending on the structure of the response.

Comment: Seems to me like you should be passing this response to a piechart/barchart component, then have the piechart component responsible for merging the relevant data based on the context of the chart.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman If I'm not mistaken, this would replace 'echartBar' with the response data. I just want to use the response data within the 'echartBar' const that was imported. I updated the second file above with 'dataNeeded' showing the data that I would like to place there from the axios response.

Comment: So let's assume you have response data, and there is a variable `response.data.months`. Did you try setting the eChart data like so: `this.echartBar.xAxis[0].data = response.data.months` ?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Awesome, that works for me. If you'd like to add that as an answer, I can mark it - that did the trick though! I'll try filling in more information and see how it behaves with a lot of data. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The const is basically returning a plain object. Axios will receive the object data, which you can simply access or assign its values to other objects.

In your case, you may assign a value to the `echartBar` object in the scope of your component like so:

```js
this.echartBar.xAxis[0].data = response.data.months
```

This assumes you have a `months` property in your response data.

This process can be cumbersome especially when you have a lot of properties on the echartBar object like you have. You'll need to check for arrays in arrays etc. Libraries like `lodash` might be helpfull in that case, for example its `set` function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set